# Should authors accept an answer when only one is given?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

If an author asks a question that only receives one answer, is the author obligated to accept it?

In [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), the defined behavior is to accept an answer after 24-48 hours but there is no mention of accepting the answer when one only one is given.

If the only given answer after 48 hours is upvoted, helpful, and minimally acceptable to the author, is the author obligated to accept it, even if the author feels a that a more comprehensive answer would better answer the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no obligation to accept an answer that doesn't satisfy you.  Further, accepting an answer will signal to other readers that you got what you needed, so you're less likely to get new answers.

If an answer doesn't help you, it's good practice to leave a comment explaining what you found missing, unclear, etc.  Try to help the answerer improve the answer.  It's also a good idea to review your question -- make sure it's as clear and well-scoped as it can be.  Ask yourself "why aren't people answering this?" and see if that suggests any improvements you can make.

(Some questions are just hard, though, and may stick around for a long time before the right expert stumbles upon them and offers a comprehensive answer.  That's fine.  If your question is one of these, you may need to promote your question to try to reach that right expert.)